# Where in the source code CyanogenMod stores default values of “Mobile data” and “Data roaming” settings?

Tags: settings, config, cyanogenmod

In what configure file(s) in the source code CyanogenMod 12.1 stores global (not overlay) default values of “Mobile data” and “Data roaming” settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/customize.xml` file:

```xml
<!-- Default for Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING -->
<bool name="def_enable_data_roaming">false</bool>

<!-- Default for Settings.Global.MOBILE_DATA -->
<bool name="def_enable_mobile_data">true</bool>
```

Comment: Mobile data can also be disabled by default on new builds with a build.prop property.

Comment: @Avamander Which property? And what about data roaming? Can it be disabled via build.prop property?